# Using SciPy curve_fit for data with multiple functional forms

Tags: scipy, curve-fitting

I'm trying to fit some data that starts out flat, sharply peaks at time=0, and then decays as two negative exponentials (first as a fast one, and then after a small amount of time as a slower one). I've been trying to use curve_fit from scipy.optimize but the fit does not seem to recognize the first fast decaying exponential.

All I do is define two fit functions for different ranges of time. For time<0 I have a constant (which I called line because at first I was using a line). For time>0 I define the sum of two exponentials with different parameters. I then make a guess for these parameters, and feed everything into curve_fit.

I'm really just wondering if anyone has any ideas about how to get it to recognize the first peak and fast decay...

In my google searches, I can only find examples for fitting simple data (such as a single exponential or polynomial). I may be approaching this completely wrong, any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Also, I would attach plots of what I get but this is my first post and I have no reputation so it won't let me...

Here is a link to the data:
http://www.lehigh.edu/~ivb2/teaching/smp/current/DecayData.txt

Here is the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import numpy as np
from scipy import optimize
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def line(x, *p):
    return p[0]

def exponential(x, *p):
    return p[0] * np.exp(p[1] * x) + p[2]

#Fit function (neg exp in this case)
def fitfunc(time, *p):
    tempArray = np.empty_like(time)
    tempArray[time <= 0] = line(time, p[6])
    tempArray[0 < time] = exponential(time, p[0], p[1], p[2]) + exponential(time, p[3], p[4], p[5])
    return tempArray

#Read in the data to 3 arrays
time, decay1, decay2 = np.loadtxt('DecayData.txt', unpack=True)

#An initial guess for the fit parameters
guess = np.array([5e-2, -2500, 0, 5e-2, -2000, 0, 0])

#Fits the functions using curve_fit
popt, pcov = curve_fit(fitfunc, time, decay1, guess)

print popt

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.plot(time, decay1)
ax.plot(time, fitfunc(time, *popt))
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see two problems:

- in `fitfunc` you write

  ```
  tempArray[time <= 0] = line(time, p[6])
  tempArray[0 < time] = exponential(time, p[0], p[1], p[2]) + exponential(time, p[3], p[4], p[5])
  ```

but the size of the arrays are not the same on the two sides of the equalities. I think on the second line the times are not good; I've replaced it with

```
    tempArray[time <= 0] = line(time[time<=0], p[6])
    tempArray[0 < time] = exponential(time[0<time], p[0], p[1], p[2]) + exponential(time[0<time], p[3], p[4], p[5])
```

- your initial guess for `p[1]` if very false, I've replaced `-2500` by `-250000`

With these two changes, it works fine on my computer.

JPG